# How should google crawl my blog?

Tags: seo, blogs

I was wondering how (or if) I should guide Googlebot through my blog. Should I only allow visiting pages with single entries or should it also crawl the main page (which also has full entries)? My concern is that the main page changes when I add a new post and google keeps the old version for some time. I also find directing people to the main page annoying - you have to look through all the post before you find the one you're interested in. So what is the proper way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not submit a [sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) with the appropriate `<changefreq>` tags -- if you set that to "always" for the homepage, the crawler will *know* that your homepage is very volatile (and you can have accurate change freq for other URLs too, of course). You can also give a lower priority to your homepage and a higher one to the pages you prefer to see higher in the index.

I do not recommend telling crawlers to avoid indexing your homepage completely, as that would throw away any link juice you might be getting from links to it from other sites -- tweaking change freq and priority seems preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Make a sitemap.xml and regenerate it periodically. Check out Google Webmaster Tools.